# how to change matplotlibrc default directory

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm currently using anaconda and python 3.6 on windows bash. Every time i want to use matplotlib I have to paste a copy of the matplotlibrc file into my working directory otherwise my code won't run or plot and I get the warning - /home/computer/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/**init**.py:1022: UserWarning: could not find rc file;returning defaults

my matplotlibrc file is located at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\lxss\home\puter\anaconda3\lib\python3.6\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data

I thought to fix this I could edit my .condarc file and set it to look for matplotlibrc in the correct directory. Could anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Just note that this is a *warning*, not an *error*. Your code will work as expected even without matplotlibrc file. Of course the warning may be annoying and getting rid of it is a valid desire.

Comment: If the matplotlibrc is indeed in the directory you say it is, I wonder where the warning comes from. By default matplotlib will look at exactly this directory, see point 4 in [The matplotlibrc file](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#the-matplotlibrc-file).

Comment: ok thanks. Even though it's a warning, none of the code will run without matplotlibrc in the working directory. It won't print anything to console, and no graph will plot in a separate window.
In bash if I enter python then  import matplotlib and I get the same warning as above

Comment: Have you tried copying the matplotlibrc file to the user directory as in point 3 of [The matplotlibrc file](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#the-matplotlibrc-file) or tried to create an evironment variable like in point 2? If matplotlib fails to run at all it might also be a totally different issue though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it set me on the right course. It looks like when I've installed anaconda or matplotlib it's created the matplotlibrc file in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\lxss\home\puter\anaconda3\lib\python3.6\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data  using the windows environment. This has caused the file not to be recognised in WSL. 

In bash I created another matplotlibrc file in the above directory and copied the contents of the previously created matplotlibrc file into it which has resolved the issue.

Comment: You may answer your own question with the solution that has worked for you to resolve the issue. Then, in two days time, accept this solution, such that the question is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like when anaconda or matplotlib was installed it's created the matplotlibrc file in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\lxss\home\puter\anaconda3\lib\py‌​thon3.6\site-package‌​s\matplotlib\mpl-dat‌​a using the windows environment. This has caused the file not to be recognised in WSL.

To fix this create another matplotlibrc file in bash or whatever shell you're using. In the directory listed above copy the contents of the previously created matplotlibrc file into your new matplotlibrc file. Make sure you don't create this file in the windows environment otherwise it won't be recognised.